# Lazy Fibonacci Sequence in Ruby

Tags: ruby, generator, lazy-sequences

Coming from Python if I wanted to create an iterative lazy Fibonacci sequence, I could do something like this:

```
def fib():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    yield a
    yield b
    while True:
        yield a + b
        tmp = a
        a = b
        b = tmp + b
```

Grabbing `next(fib)`  will give me the next element in the sequence by simply adding the previous two elements, so if I want to get the first 1000 Fibonacci elements, I can do that quickly:

```
fib = fib()
for i in range(0,1000):
    print(next(fib))
```

[If I try to reproduce that in Ruby with an Enumerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173159/lazy-fibonacci-in-ruby), it quickly chokes, recalculating the entire sequence each time we call fib.next():

```
def fib()
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
        yielder << 1 << 2
        fib.lazy.zip(fib.lazy.drop(1)).each do |a,b|
            yielder << a + b
        end
    end
end
```

I found another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438655/ruby-fibonacci-algorithm/24439070) on how to fix a recursive fibonacci with memoization in Ruby, but I am curious, are lazy sequences and generators a thing in Ruby?

Comment: The documentation for [`Enumerator.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-new) shows how to create an enumerator for Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use recursive enumerators but do it like in Python? With a loop?

```
def fib()
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    a, b = 1, 2
    yielder << a << b
    loop do
      a, b = b, a + b
      yielder << b
    end
  end
end
```

What you did there in Ruby looks in Python like this:

```
def fib():
    yield from (1, 2)
    for a, b in zip(fib(), islice(fib(), 1, None)):
        yield a + b
```

That's slow as well.

Btw, worse than the exponential time is the exponential amount of memory. That recursive Python version **crashes** for me when trying to compute the 32nd Fibonacci number. At that point I already have almost 4 million generators running. And your Ruby version crashes for me when trying to compute the 20th Fibonacci number, with error `can't create fiber (FiberError)`. At that point I have almost 12000 fibers running.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I get for not understanding Ruby!

Comment: In case it's not evident, `enum = fib #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x000000011dd4f8>:each>; enum.next #=> 1; enum.next #=> 2; enum.next #=> 3; enum.next #=> 5; enum.next #=> 8` and so on.